# A quadratic Diophantine equation involving $3n^2-n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I got this question from a colleague who likes to solve Diophantine equations.

Find integer solution(s) for
$\qquad\dfrac{m}{n}+ \dfrac{n+1}{m}=4$

Clearly $\space\space  m=-4 \space\space $
and
$\space\space  n=-1\space\space  $ is a solution, but we are wondering whether there are others.

What we have tried is that we got
$\space \space m^2-4mn+n^2+n=0\space \space $
and thus it must be the case that
$\space \space 3n^2-n\space \space $ is a perfect square. Then we are a bit stuck.

Comment: One additional bit of information you can get from the initial equation is that if $n$ is even, then $m$ can't be odd, because even numbers never divide odd numbers. For the same reason, $n+1$ cannot be odd if $m$ is even.

Comment: @maomao FYI, using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7Bm%7D%7Bn%7D%2B%20%5Cfrac%7Bn%2B1%7D%7Bm%7D%3D4%24&p=1), I found re: natural solutions [There does not exist natural numbers such that $\frac{m}{n}+\frac{n+1}{m}=4$.](/q/2287494), [Proving there exist no positive integers $m,n$ such that $ m/n +(n+1)/m = 4$](/q/651706), [Show that there do not exist any integer $m,n$ such that $\frac{m}{n}+\frac{n+1}{m}=4$](/q/1963412) and [Prove there is no $x, y \in \mathbb Z^+ \text{ satisfying } \frac{x}{y} +\frac{y+1}{x}=4$](/q/2853669). ...

Comment: @maomao (cont.) Also, closely related is the only integer solution among positive integers $m$ & $n$ is $3$, as indicated in [If $\frac{a+1}{b}+\frac{b}{a}$ is an integer then it is $3$.](/q/1120083) and the AoPS thread [one integer](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1591107p9862458).

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1046758__  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1046841___

Answer (score 1):

Some algebraic manipulation shows that your equation, for $m,n\neq0$, is equivalent to
$$(6n-1)^2-3(2m-4n)^2=1.\tag{1}$$
This is a [Pell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation); setting $X:=6n-1$ and $Y:=2m-4n$ this is simply
$$X^2-3Y^2=1.$$
Its integral solutions are well known; they are precisely the pairs of integers $(X_k,Y_k)$ of the form
$$X_k+Y_k\sqrt{3}=\pm(2+\sqrt{3})^k,\tag{2}$$
for some integer $k$. We get a corresponding solution to $(1)$ if and only if $X_k\equiv5\pmod{6}$ and $Y_k\equiv0\pmod{2}$. This happens precisely when $k$ is even and we have the $-$-sign in $(2)$. So the solutions to your equation are precisely the pairs $(m,n)$ of the form
$$m=\frac{3Y_l+2X_l+2}{6}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad n=\frac{X_l+1}{6},$$
where $X_l$ and $Y_l$ are the integers defined by
$$X_l+Y_l\sqrt{3}=-(7+4\sqrt{3})^l.$$
For a few small values this yields the following solutions $(m,n)$:
$$\begin{array}{r|rr}
l&m&n&\\
\hline
-3&-60&-225\\
-2&-4&-16\\
-1&0&-1\\
0&0&0\\
1&-4&-1\\
2&-60&-16\\
3&-840&-225\\
\end{array}$$
Note that $l=-1$ and $l=0$ yields solutions to $(1)$, but not to the original equation.

Answer (score 0):

$3n^2 - n - k^2 = 0 \implies \triangle = 1+12k^2 = m^2 \implies m^2 - 3(2k)^2 = 1$. This Diophantine equation is known to have infinite solutions: with the initial one is $(m,k) = (7,2)$, and the next ones are : $(2m+6k,m+4k)$.